# Remove default window from main.storyboard OSX

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

I am using XCode 6.1.1 on OSX 10.10
I am creating a Cocoa Menu bar extra.
I have create a new project and selected "Use storyboard" option.
How do I disable the "Visible at launch" of default window.
I also tried deleting the default window controller, still a window is shown at app launch.

It used to work fine for the default Mainmenu.xib, but when I enable storyboard, I dont find any option to disable the "Visible at launch" option

Comment: you want to delete the launch view?

Comment: @WorldOfWarcraft Yes. The default window should not be visible initially.

Comment: had you delete `hadLaunchScreen.xib` ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to get rid of the arrow in the storyboard?

In the Main.storyboard file, select the Window Controller. In the Attributes section, there should be an option "Is Initial Controller." Selecting a non-initial window controller for this option will deselect the current initial window (if there is any) and set that as the initial window. Deselecting the current initial window will make it so that there is no initial window.